# How to concatenate items from loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wonder if there's a quick way to concatenate the items from this view helper with a comma:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= link_to project.name, project_path(project) %>
<% end %>
```

so that I get:

[Project name 1](http://www.example.org), [Project name 2](http://www.example.org), [Project name 3](http://www.example.org)

Note that there's no comma at the end. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
<%= @projects.map { |p| link_to p.name, project_path(p) }.join(', ').html_safe %>
```

<del>I added `sanitize` to `p.name` because otherwise if some special character is present in `p.name` it would break your HTML (and could lead to security issues, that is XSS attacks)</del> I was wrong, I tried and it is escaped correctly.

Comment: use `raw` or `html_safe`

Comment: Uhmmmm so `p.name` should be sanitized... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= @projects.map {|project| link_to project.name, project_path(project)}.join(", ").html_safe %>
```